# Colorbar Labelpad in mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.ImageGrid

Tags: matplotlib, label, colorbar, pad

i am creating an ImageGrid like this:

```
axs = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(1, 2), axes_pad=0.2, share_all=True,
             cbar_location="top", cbar_mode='single', cbar_size="2.5%", cbar_pad=0.35)
```

then i add a colorbar like this:

```
cb = axs[0].cax.colorbar(im)
cb.set_label_text('Some Text')
```

Any ideas on how to change the padding between the colorbar and it's label? Especially in the configuration chosen above with the colorbor above the images, the label seems to collide with the ticklabels of the colorbar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
cb.ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(x, y)
```

However, i don't think this is a very pretty solution. Maybe there is a better one.